# asio high_resolution_timer segmentation fault in async_wait

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, boost-asio

I have implemented a task queue with priority from [asio examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp) and a timer class which use this queue. Here is the code:

#### priority_task_queue.h

```
class handler_priority_queue
{
private:
    class queued_handler{
    private:
        size_t _priority;
        std::function<void()> _function;
    public:
        queued_handler(size_t p, std::function<void()> f): _priority(p), _function(f){}
        friend bool operator<(const queued_handler& a, const queued_handler& b){
            return a._priority < b._priority;
        }
        void operator()() {
            _function();
        }
    };
    std::priority_queue<queued_handler> _handlers;

public:
    // A generic wrapper class for handlers to allow the invocation to be hooked.
    template <typename Handler> class wrapped_handler
    {
        private:
            handler_priority_queue& _queue;
            size_t _priority;
            Handler _handler;

        public:
            handler_priority_queue& queue() {return _queue;}
            size_t priority() {return _priority;}

            wrapped_handler(handler_priority_queue& q, size_t p, Handler h)
                : _queue(q), _priority(p), _handler(h){}


            template <typename ...Args>
            void operator()(Args&&... args){
                _handler(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
    };
    template <typename Handler> wrapped_handler<Handler> wrap(size_t priority, Handler handler){
        return wrapped_handler<Handler>(*this, priority, handler);
    }
    void add(size_t priority, std::function<void()> function);
    void execute_all();
    void execute_one();
    bool empty();
};

// Custom invocation hook for wrapped handlers.
template <typename Function, typename Handler>
void asio_handler_invoke(Function f, handler_priority_queue::wrapped_handler<Handler>* h){
    h->queue().add(h->priority(), f);
    std::cout<<"LLAMANDO AL INVOKE"<<std::endl; //BORRAR!!
}

class C_priority_task_queue{

    private:
        asio::io_service& _io;
        handler_priority_queue _pri_queue;

    public:
        template <typename Handler> handler_priority_queue::wrapped_handler<Handler> wrap(int priority, Handler handler){
            return _pri_queue.wrap(priority, handler);
        }

        explicit C_priority_task_queue(asio::io_service& io): _io(io){}
        C_priority_task_queue(C_priority_task_queue const&) = delete;
        C_priority_task_queue& operator =(C_priority_task_queue const&) = delete;

        asio::io_service& io() {return _io;}
        void run();
};
```

#### priority_task_queue.cpp

```
void handler_priority_queue::add(size_t priority, std::function<void()> function){
    _handlers.push(queued_handler(priority, function));
}

void handler_priority_queue::execute_one(){
    if(!_handlers.empty()){
        queued_handler handler = _handlers.top();
        handler();
        _handlers.pop();
    }
}

bool handler_priority_queue::empty(){
    return _handlers.empty();
}

void C_priority_task_queue::run(){
    while (_io.run_one())
    {
        _io.poll();
        while(!_pri_queue.empty())
        {
            _io.poll();
            _pri_queue.execute_one();
        }
    }
}
```

### base_timer.h

```
class C_timer {
    private:
        asio::high_resolution_timer _timer;
        uint8_t _timer_id; 
        C_priority_task_queue& _prio_queue;


    void timer_handler_internal(const asio::error_code& e, uint8_t timer_id, const uint64_t sched_time);
    virtual void timer_handler(const uint64_t sched_time)=0;

    public:
        size_t _priority;
        explicit C_timer(C_priority_task_queue& prio_queue, size_t priority);
        virtual ~C_timer();

        void set_timer(uint64_t sched_time);
        int cancel();
};
```

### base_timer.cpp

```
C_timer::C_timer(C_priority_task_queue& prio_queue, size_t priority):
        _timer(prio_queue.io()), _timer_id(0), _prio_queue(prio_queue), _priority(priority){}

C_timer::~C_timer(){}

void C_timer::set_timer(uint64_t sched_time){
    ++_timer_id;

    _timer.expires_at(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>(std::chrono::milliseconds(sched_time)));
    _timer.async_wait(_prio_queue.wrap(_priority, std::bind(&C_timer::timer_handler_internal, this,
                      std::placeholders::_1/*error*/, _timer_id, sched_time)));
}

int C_timer::cancel(){
    ++_timer_id;
    return _timer.cancel();
}

void C_timer::timer_handler_internal(const asio::error_code& e, uint8_t timer_id,
                                               const uint64_t sched_time){
    if(e==asio::error::operation_aborted || timer_id != _timer_id){
        return;
    }
    timer_handler(sched_time);
}
```

### test class

```
class C_timer_test: public C_timer{
    private:
        int _period;

        virtual void timer_handler(const uint64_t sched_time) override{
            std::cout<<"timer fired"<<std::endl;

            uint64_t current_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
            set_timer(current_time + _period);
        }

    public:
        C_timer_test(C_priority_task_queue& prio_queue, int priority, int period):C_timer(prio_queue, priority), _periodo(period){}
        virtual ~C_timer_test(){}
        void run(uint64_t delay=0){
            uint64_t time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
            set_timer(time + delay);
        }
};
```

The problem is if I execute this :

```
int main()
{
    asio::io_service io;
    C_priority_task_queue prio_queue(io);
    asio::io_service::work w(io);

  C_timer_test ti1(prio_queue, 0, 2000);
  ti1.run();
  prio_queue.run();

  return 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault.

However, if I execute the following code it works fine:

```
int main()
{
    asio::io_service io;
    C_priority_task_queue prio_queue(io);
    asio::high_resolution_timer _timer1(io);
    asio::io_service::work w(io);

  C_timer_test ti1(prio_queue, 0, 2000);
  ti1.run();
  prio_queue.run();

  return 0;
}
```

The only diference between both piece of code is in the second main I have added the following line `asio::high_resolution_timer _timer1(io);` that I haven't use in any place.

Debugging the program I have found that the signal is raising in this line:
`func_(&owner, this, ec, bytes_transferred);` in file `task_io_service_operation.hpp`

I am using asio version 1.10.6.

Any suggestion that what could be happening?

The backtrace from gdb:

```
gdb ./main 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
(gdb) r
[libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0805f0d4 in ?? ()
(gdb) backtrace 
#0  0x0805f0d4 in ?? ()
#1  0x080529fb in asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one (this=0x805f030, lock=..., this_thread=..., ec=...) at /src/cpp/external_lib/asio/include/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:371
#2  0x080526ce in asio::detail::task_io_service::run_one (this=0x805f030, ec=...) at /src/cpp/external_lib/asio/include/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:169
#3  0x08052c68 in asio::io_service::run_one (this=0xbffff08c) at /src/cpp/external_lib/asio/include/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:71
#4  0x08051f32 in C_priority_task_queue::run (this=0xbffff094) at priority_task_queue.cpp:19
#5  0x08049ac3 in main () at main.cpp:46
```

And here there is the MakeFile:

```
TARGET=main
SOURCES=  main.cpp base_timer.cpp  priority_task_queue.cpp
SOURCE_DIR=.
INCLUDE_LIB= -L/src/cpp/libcore
INCLUDE_DIR=-I/src/cpp/external_lib/asio/include \
             -I/src/cpp/libcore/include
INSTALL_DIR=.
LIB=-pthread
CXX=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -fexceptions -fpermissive -std=c++11 -DASIO_STANDALONE
CFLAGS_DEBUG = -g3 -DDEBUG
OBJDIR_DEBUG=obj
BINDIR_DEBUG=.
OBJECTS_DEBUG:= $(addprefix $(OBJDIR_DEBUG)/,$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))

all: debug

$(OBJDIR_DEBUG)/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp
    @test -d $(OBJDIR_DEBUG) || mkdir -p $(OBJDIR_DEBUG)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_DEBUG) $(INCLUDE_DIR) -c $< -o $@

debug: $(OBJECTS_DEBUG)
    @test -d $(BINDIR_DEBUG) || mkdir -p $(BINDIR_DEBUG)
    $(CXX) -o $(BINDIR_DEBUG)/$(TARGET) $^ $(INCLUDE_LIB) $(LIB)
```

### UPDATE

I my investigation, I have found that if I define the base_timer members (basically asio::high_resolution_timer) initializations in the .h, the code runs ok, but if I do this in the .cpp, the code crash.

I mean,

```
explicit C_timer(C_priority_task_queue& prio_queue, size_t priority):
        _timer(prio_queue.io()), _timer_id(0), _prio_queue(prio_queue), _priority(priority){}
```

in .h works, but

```
C_timer::C_timer(C_priority_task_queue& prio_queue, size_t priority): 
   _timer(prio_queue.io()), _timer_id(0), _prio_queue(prio_queue), _priority(priority){}
```

in .cpp fails

Comment: I think you are missing a call to `io.run()`.  The `io_service` class needs a thread on which to run.  Edit: the `run_one()` calls may be insufficient, and you should probably have one thread for the `io_service` to run on anyway if you are planning on using timers with it.

Comment: @nimble_ninja That isnt the problem. Just that part is taken from asio example (doing while(io.run_one()) is the same as call io.run()). Anyway, As I metioned in the question, if I added this line, asio::high_resolution_timer _timer1(io), that has nothing to do with the rest of the code, the program run perfectly. If I ommit it, it throw a segmentation fault.

Comment: What happens when you run it in a debugger? What is the backtrace of the crash?

Comment: except for "unnatural" juggling with chrono (timepoint or duration, pick one!) the code looks ok. I can't reproduce any failure (GCC, linux): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33f400874358b133

Comment: If adding random variables make problems appear/disappear, you should think of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), use static analysis, valgrind/purify/... and code scrutiny to find your culprit. Valgrind, ASAN and UBSAN ran clean on my PC

Comment: @sehe thanks for your effort. The diference is If I put every code into a single file, main.cpp, it runs, but if I separate into several files, the problem still there. In other hand, If I instanciate a high_resolution_timer object in the main.cpp, no matter the place (inside main(), in separate function that never is called, ...) it runs, but without it, a segmentation fault is raised.

Comment: Another observation is that I am not using boost libraries, i am using C++11 (non-boost) version and compiling with -DASIO_STANDALONE flag. I dont know if this have something related with the issue.

Comment: Its not good to write "I get a segmentation fault" without the backtrace. Post backtrace, so probably someone can find trouble fast.

Comment: @kfsone I have updated the post and I added the backtrace from gdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had been using the version 1.10.2 of the library and it seems there was a bug.

I have updated to the last version 1.10.6 and now it runs ok.

Comment: It "seems" there was a bug? I wouldn't be able to sleep well if I didn't know for sure what bug and _that_ it was fixed.

Comment: The earliest change in the release history that would seem reasonably suspect in relation to your symptoms would be [_"Fixed delegation of continuation hook for handlers produced by io_service::wrap() and strand::wrap()."_](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.6/doc/asio/history.html#asio.history.asio_1_10_6) but that was fixed _in_ 1.10.2, not after. Hmm. No time to track it down :(

Comment: @sehe I have downloaded the asio repository from [here](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/) and I look through the commits from version 1.10.2 to version 1.10.6, but due to i am not an expert in metaprogramming,I am not very sure where it was the bug. Maybe the commit df2e96d0 _"Fix unsigned int overflow reported by clang's integer sanitizer."_??

Comment: @Aaronux Stepping through the debugger may provide details about the crash.  In the backtrace, [frame 1](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/asio-1-10-2/asio/include/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp#L371) is invoking a function that [calls a static function via a pointer](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/asio-1-10-2/asio/include/asio/detail/task_io_service_operation.hpp#L37).  With frame 0 having an unknown symbol name, I would be suspicious of translation units compiler flags, particularly `priority_task_queue.o`.

Comment: @TannerSansbury priority_task_queue isnt the problem. before reaching to the issue with the asio versions, I tried to isolate the bug, recoding the program without using priority queue, deleting both class files. Then I changed the base_timer class async_wait call to this new one `_timer.async_wait( std::bind(&C_timer::timer_handler_internal, this,
                      std::placeholders::_1/*error*/, _timer_id, sched_time));` and the problem continued.

Comment: @TannerSansbury When the code was ok (defining constructor in header), [this condition](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/asio-1-10-2/asio/include/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp#L340) was True and the function pointer was not called, but when its raise a segmentation fault the condition was False.

Comment: This has the smell of a thread-unsafe operation that you are getting away with when you change the duration of the first slice. I would set a break point at `while (_io.run_one())` in `C_priority_task_queue::run` and see if the problem still happens when you set a break point there, and whether it happens on the first iteration of the loop or not.

Comment: @kfsone that smell would be theoretically undistinguishable from any other UB smell (like I suggested). For one thing there are no threads (outside potentially lib-internal threads). I have a sense there's a dangling reference problem which leads to a stray write/read and the removal/re-organizing of code makes the memory layout different so the problem manifests more/less.

Answer (score 0):

Except for "unnatural" juggling with chrono (timepoint or duration, pick one!) the code looks ok. I can't reproduce any failure (GCC, linux):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33f400874358b133)</kbd>**

If adding random variables make problems appear/disappear, you should think of Undefined Behaviour, use static analysis, valgrind/purify/... and code scrutiny to find your culprit. Valgrind, ASAN and UBSAN ran clean on my PC

> @sehe thanks for your effort. The diference is If I put every code into a single file, main.cpp, it runs, but if I separate into several files, the problem still there. In other hand, If I instanciate a high_resolution_timer object in the main.cpp, no matter the place (inside main(), in separate function that never is called, ...) it runs, but without it, a segmentation fault is raised.

That's great: you have found a *potential* source of the UB: look at the use of static variables or inline functions that are not ODR-safe. (Double check all translation units are using the same compiler flags).

Also, keep in mind **[UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** is *UNDEFINED*, so like adding an unrelated `_timer1` changes the apparent behaviour (without changing the *source* of UB) the same thing could make it *appear* to work.

The fact that it runs clean on my machine tells you that this would have to be a platform-specific source of UB

Comment: I added the makefile to the post. I had though it had be something related with global/static variables. I though that asio was a mature library and free for this kind of behaviour. I looking for in the official documentation but i am not able to find anything related with the global or static variables recomendations or issues in asio sources.

Comment: Nobody said the cause is in library code. In fact [that's highly unlikely](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/). I was referring to your code. I haven't looked. Can you compare with Boost Asio (assuming Asio 1.10.6 means standalone version?). Perhaps it's time for a support ticket there

Comment: `-DASIO_STANDALONE` might indeed be involved, try using a linked lib if that is supported. If that matters then it's 90% an ODR issue (check for different compilation flags/compiler versions between translation units; e.g. do full rebuild, bypass ccache etc.). In the remaining 10% chance there could be an issue in the Asio headers (perhaps conflicting file-statics). I'm just guessing. Hope it helps

Comment: the code i posted it is all program. To think that the cause is in library is my last card, due to I have isolated and revised entire code and I couldn't find any issue. However, my knowledge in template programming in C++ is very limited, so I don't known if I am doing anything wrong, taking into account that asio is enterily metaprograming.

Comment: To use `-DASIO_STANDALONE` flag is a requeriment of the program, because i dont want to have dependencies with the rest of boost libraries, and setting this flag is the only way i can use C++11 classes.

Comment: I found that if it is defined C_timer's asio::high_resolution_timer member initialization in .h, it works, but if I do in .cpp, it fails with segmentation fault. Any idea what could be happening? maybe something related with what you say about ODR, but how could I check where is the bug?

Comment: I have resolved it. The problem was that i have been using an outdate version of the library and it is seems that was a bug in this version. Finally it was a bug in the library, as i mentioned in a previous comment ;) thanks for your help